# Filter select fields based on previous select fields values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, drop-down-menu, filter

I'm new at RoR and I'm having a trouble in my app. The problem consists on filter a select field named "Solution", based on the others select fields above it.

Now, what the app do is to retrieve all information from BD about Area, Region, Associated, Solution and populate the select fields with these data. But the user wants that, when an area, a region and an associated is selected by the user, only the solutions about that associated in that region on that area should be shown.

Edit:

I'm almost there! I've made many changes in my app. The select fields are populated by controller action new and the function "populate_selects", which is called by the parameter `before_action :popula_selects, only: [:new, :edit]`. A new function was created in order to be called by AJAX and upgrade the "Solution" field:

```
Atendments_Controller  < ApplicationController

before_action :populate_selects, only: [:new, :edit]

def new 
  @atend = atendment.new
end

def update_solution #AJAX
  @solutions = atendment.joins(:solution).where("atendment_area_id = ? and atendment_region_id = ? and atendment_assoc_id = ?", params[:atendment_area_id], params[:atendment_region_id], params[:atendment_assoc_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end

private

def populate_selects
  @atendment_area = atendmentArea.where(status: true, user_id: current_user.id)
  @atendment_region = atendmentRegion.where(status: true, user_id: current_user.id)
  @atendment_assoc = atendmentRegionAssoc.where(status: true, assoc_id: current_user.entidade_id).where(atendment_region_id: @atendment_region.map(&:atendment_region_id))
  @solutions = atendment.joins(:solution).where("atendment_area_id = ? and atendment_region_id = ? and atendment_assoc_id = ?", params[:atendment_area_id], params[:atendment_region_id], params[:atendment_region_assoc_id])

  end
end
```

Below, the _form.html.erb code from view:

```
<div class="atendment-form">
  <%= form_for :atendment, url: {action: "new"}, html: {method: "get"} do |f| %>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <%= f.select :atendment_area_id, options_for_select(@atendment_area.collect { |c| [ c.atendment_area.name, c.id ] }, 1), {:prompt=>"Área"}, { :class => 'form-control', :required => true, id: 'atendment_atendment_area_id' } %>
      </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <%= f.select :atendment_region_id, options_for_select(@atendment_region.collect { |c| [ c.atendment_region.name, c.id ] }, 1), {:prompt=>"Região"}, { :class => 'form-control', :required => true, id: 'atendment_atendment_region_id' } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.select :atendment_assoc_id, options_for_select(@atendment_assoc.collect { |c| [ c.atendment_region.name, c.id ] }, 1), {:prompt=>"Associado"}, { :class => 'form-control', :required => true, id: 'atendment_atendment_assoc_id' } %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.select :solution_id, options_for_select(@solutions.collect { |solution| [solution.name, solution.id] }, 0), {:prompt=>"Solução"}, { :class => 'form-control', :required => true, id: 'atendment_solution_id' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Route to the new function:

```
resources :atendments do
collection do
  get :update_solution
  end
end
```

AJAX function which calls the "update_solution" and reset solution field's value (app/assets/javascript/atendment.js.coffee):

```
show_solutions = ->

$.ajax 'update_solution',
type: 'GET'
dataType: 'script'
data: {
  atendment_area_id: $("#atendment_atendment_area_id").val()
  atendment_region_id: $("#atendment_atendment_region_id").val()
  atendment_assoc_id: $("#atendment_atendment_assoc_id").val()
}
error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
  console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
  console.log("OK!")

$(document).ready ->

  $('#atendment_atendment_assoc_id').on 'change', ->
    show_solutions()
```

So, I've created a .coffee file to render the partial that will return a new value to the "solution" field "option" tag
 (app/views/atendment/update_solution.coffee):

```
$("#atendment_solution_id").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'solution') %>")
```

And, the last but not least, the partial containing the html code for the "option" tag mentioned above (app/views/atendments/_solution.html.erb):

```
<option value="<%= solution.id %>" selected="selected"><%= solution.nome %></option>
```

For any reason, the AJAX function doesn't print nothing on console (nor error neither success), but it calls the update_solution.coffee file. The point is, it doesn't update the option value due an error **(500 internal server error)**. I don't know what am I doing wrong. If anybody could help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following code:

assets/js/atendments.js 
I changed the code because the last one had many bugs.

```
function getAssociated(){

  var aau_id = $("#atendment_area_user_id").val() 
  var aru_id = $("#atendment_region_user_id").val();

  $.getJSON("/controllers/atendments_controller/getAssociated/"+aru_id,
    function ( callback ) {
    if (callback != "error"){

      var assoc = document.getElementById("atendment_region_associated_id");

      while (assoc.firstChild) {
        assoc.removeChild(assoc.firstChild);
      }

      var i = Object.keys(callback).length -1;

      $("#atendment_region_associated_id").append("<option value=''>Associated</option>");

      while (i >= 0) {
        $("#atendment_region_associated_id").append("<option value='"+callback[Object.keys(callback)[i]]+"'>"+Object.keys(callback)[i]+"</option>");
        i--;
      }
    }
  });
  get_solution_type();
}

function get_solution_type() {

  var ara_id = $("#atendment_region_associated_id").val();

  $.getJSON("/controllers/atendments_controller/getSolution/"+ara_id,
    function ( callback ) {

    if (callback != "error"){

      var sol = document.getElementById("atendment_solution_id");
      while (sol.firstChild) {
        sol.removeChild(sol.firstChild);
      }
      var i = Object.keys(callback).length-1;
      while (i >= 0) {
        $("#atendment_solution_id").append("<option value='"+callback[Object.keys(callback)[i]]+"'>"+Object.keys(callback)[i]+"</option>");
        i--;
      }
    }
  }); 

  var aau_id = $("#atendment_area_user_id").val();

  $.getJSON("/controllers/atendments_controller/getType/"+aau_id,
    function ( callback ) {

    if (callback != "erro"){

      var type = document.getElementById("atendment_type_id");
      while (type.firstChild) {
        type.removeChild(type.firstChild);
      }
      var i = 0;
      while (i < (Object.keys(callback).length)) {
        $("#atendment_type_id").append("<option value='"+callback[Object.keys(callback)[i]]+"'>"+Object.keys(callback)[i]+"</option>");
        i++;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The `$.getJSON` performs ajax request to the controller that responds with JSON and update the select fields option tags.

controllers/atendments_controller 
I just retrieve the data from DB and return as JSON

```
def getAssociated
  aru_id = params[:atendment_region_user_id]
  aras = AtendmentRegionAssociated.where("SQL here")

  if aras.present?
    render :json => aras.to_json
  else
    render :json => "error".to_json
  end

end

def getSolution
  ara_id = params[:atendment_region_associated_id]

  sol = Solution.where("SQL here")

  if sol.present?
    render :json => sol.to_json
  else
    render :json => "error".to_json
  end

end

def getType
  aau_id = params[:atendment_area_user_id]
  type = AtendmentType.where("SQL here")

  if type.present?
    render :json => type.to_json
  else
    render :json => "error".to_json
  end

end
```

Update the `routes` and put the javascript functions in select fields `onchange` property. Now everything is working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with JS, can think any other way.

A function called by onchange that change the display attribute from each field that you need to hide or show.